# Kestrel hosting basics

Tags: asp.net-core

I am in the process of developing an ASP.NET website, and I'm very intrigued by using vNext to host my website regardless of host. When I start looking for some of the basic hosting features though, I seem to think that they might not get developed. Does anyone know if the following features are going to be supported with vNext hosting with Kestrel on all platforms:

1. SSL hosting
2. Logging of HTTP requests (like IIS)
3. IIS modules (I'm guessing not, I only need url rewrite to redirect to HTTPS)

Answer (score 12):

As stated on the [KestrelHttpServer](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) repo:

> This repo contains a development web server for ASP.NET vNext based on libuv.

Because it is currently slated as a development server, some features might never make their way in. For example, IIS has features for controlling IP address mapping to hostnames, limitations on bandwidth/memory/CPU, etc. A development server generally wouldn't have such features.

As to IIS modules, I can comfortably say that it definitely won't support them because they are IIS-specific, and Kestrel has nothing to do with IIS.

Regarding SSL hosting, that's certainly an interesting possibility, but it's not currently in the plans. That would certainly seem useful even for a development web server (IIS Express supports it).

**Update:**
The repo documentation has been updated as of Sept 1 so it now reads:

> This repo contains a web server for ASP.NET Core based on libuv.

Comment: So I see Kestrel isn't supposed to be a hosting server. Looking over the server list, there is Helios (IIS, looks Windows dependant), Weblistener (http.sys wrapper, looks Windows dependant), or Kestrel. Is there a planned production hosting server for vNext on Mac and Linux?

Comment: We (I'm on the ASP.NET team) are contemplating making Kestrel work for production, but writing a production server is probably at least a couple of orders of magnitude more work than a dev-only server.

Comment: Would it be possible to use nginx as a production front end and a fastCGI for the kestrel or something? I don't even want to go to Apache because that would just run really slow and defeat to object of configuring a slim Linux server.

Comment: @ppumkin using nginx as a reverse proxy is definitely a great way to add functionality to any web server.

Comment: Thanks Eilon, I am trying to get this working with using reverse proxy with kestrel right now. Thank you for providing and embedded answer :]

Comment: @Elion - if there are any updates at this point on whether or not kestrel is going to be made into a production-ready server, could you please add an update here or link to relevant information?

Comment: @BenBurns no updates at this time. It's quite possible that like other "mini web servers" that exist on other platforms, it will be recommended to use a reverse proxy such as [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/) in front of it to handle things such as SSL and other protections.

Comment: @Eilon - Notwithstanding lack of SSL or other features, is Kestrel's raw performance suitable for production use?  I take it for granted that any modern "self-hosting" app (e.g. Node, Go, etc) will be proxied by Nginx or Apache or whatever.  The more important question is whether ASP.NET 5's self-hosting bits can scale, regardless?  Kestrel's documentation describing it as a "development server" makes me wary... what exactly IS the production hosting story for ASP.NET 5 on Linux going to be?

Comment: @StevePerkins we think the ultimate answer will be Kestrel. However, we haven't been able to spend as much time on it as we'd like, and so making any kind of guarantee or recommendation is a bit difficult. Both Kestrel and Node have a dependency on `libuv`, but beyond that the two servers of course diverge. Until the ASP.NET team (my team) can run serious perf and stress tests on it it'll be difficult to make promises.

Answer (score 5):

You can run kestrel behind nginx server. It will give you SSL, virtual host and other functionality. But kestrel still really unstable, so you should think twice before using it in production. Here is an article with instruction [how to configure nginx to pass requests to the kestrel](http://druss.co/2015/06/asp-net-5-kestrel-nginx-web-server-on-linux/)

Comment: Be sure you're aware of this pre-RC2 issue: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/406

Answer (score 4):

Here is a small update as Kestrel is becoming production ready

> If deploying on Linux, you should run a comparable reverse proxy
>   server such as Apache or Nginx to proxy requests to Kestrel.
>   http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#choosing-a-server

And new ASP.NET 5/Core projects come with this in there project.json

```
"commands": {
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
```

which will soon become:

```
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
```

The sample app logging seems good and it supports SSL, see [SampleApp/Startup.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/0cffed76df2c33cb93173256b0744a585a958250/samples/SampleApp/Startup.cs#L33)

Watch this space...

Comment: When approx is soon?

Comment: RC2 is still TBD on the [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) also see the linked [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/02/01/an-update-on-asp-net-core-and-net-core/)

Comment: And now [the schedule](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/06/net-core-rc2-improvements-schedule-and-roadmap/) is for rc2 "mid-May" and RTM "end of June" but note the tooling are versioned "Preview" 1 and 2 respectively